# SQL update with more than 2 records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update column in this table:

```
Date1        Date2
-------------------
2020-09-01   NULL
2020-09-02   NULL
```

Expected result:

```
Date1        Date2
----------------------
2020-09-01   Tuesday
2020-09-02   Wednesday
```

And this is my update query - I get an error and I'm not sure where the issue comes from. Thank you.

```
UPDATE table
SET Date2 = (select DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date1) from table)
```

Error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No subquery is needed:

```
UPDATE table
    SET Date2 = DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date1);
```

That said, storing such redundant information is usually not a good idea.  You can just call the function.

Comment: Forgot to tell you , the field Date1 is nvarchar.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the value of `Date2` is based on the value of `date1`, then why not just use a calculated column instead?

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.[table] DROP COLUMN date2;
ALTER TABLE dbo.[table] ADD date2 AS DATENAME(WEEKDAY,date1);
```

Comment: @qphan the second line ....ADD date2 .....  so you will have both columns?

Comment: There *would* be 2 columns, @qphan . the advantage here, as well, is that if you change the value of `date1`, the value of `date2` changes too (as it's calculated at the time the column is returned to the application layer). So, if `date1` had a value of `2020-09-25` and was updated to `2020-09-26`, `date2`'s value would change to `'Saturday'` (or the relevant day in your language), not remain as the value `'Friday'` (or whatever it was when the column was last updated).

Comment: Note that the value of `date2` in this scenario cannot be `PERSISTED`, as `DATENAME` is *not* deterministic.